# Why my constructor can not allocate memory

Tags: c++, pointers, constructor, hashmap, hashtable

I am trying for write a hash map, but the constructor won't allocate memory, can someone help me out, I am new to code, sorry for bother you guys, but I will be really appreciated for your help.

```
class HashMap {
private:
  HashEntry **table;
  int count;
  int TABLE_SIZE;
public:
  HashMap()
  {
      TABLE_SIZE = 128;
      table = new HashEntry*[TABLE_SIZE];
        for (int i = 0; i < TABLE_SIZE; i++)
              table[i] = NULL;
      count=0;
  }
}

class HashEntry 
{
private:
      int key;
      int value;
public:
    HashEntry(){}
    ~HashEntry(){}
      HashEntry(int key, int value) {
            this->key = key;
            this->value = value;
      }

      int getKey() {
            return key;
      }

      int getValue() {
            return value;
      }

      void setValue(int value) {
            this->value = value;
      }
};
```

When it runs,

```
table = new HashEntry*[TABLE_SIZE];
```

the table was unable to read memory, I am newbie in coding, plz give me some help, thanks!

Comment: What does "table was unable to read memory," mean ? What happens, what  did you expect to happen ?

Comment: Side note: the 3 lines in the middle of the constructor can be typed more concisely as: `table = new HashEntry*[TABLE_SIZE]();`

Comment: Is this your actual code? It compiles (when I add a fwd declaration and the missing semi colon) and runs ok in VS2012, though will obviously memory leak

Comment: You've allocated a table of pointers, but they don't point to anything yet. At some point you'll need to allocate the entries themselves, and assign those pointers to `table[i]`. But that's going to get messy since you'll need to handle a dynamically changing number of entries for each hash index. You'll be much better off using containers like `vector`, unless this is an educational exercise in pointer-juggling.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an array of your objects via `malloc()`, which allows you to allocate memory dynamically. I could not test this code yet, but it should work the way it is:

```
HashEntry* table;
int TABLE_SIZE;

HashMap(){

TABLE_SIZE = 128;
table = (HashEntry*)malloc(sizeof(HashEntry) * TABLE_SIZE);

    for(int i = 0; i < TABLE_SIZE; i++){

    table[i] = NULL; //If you want to create your objects, you need to replace `NULL` with `new HashEntry()`

    }

}
```